# Piping a file from the command line in C

Tags: c, file, command-line, io

I need to access a file provided to the program from the command line in the following fashion: `./myProgram < filename`

I figured you could do this with command line arguments (argv and argc), but now realize that this is not the case. I was just wondering where this file is inputted to (name or otherwise) so I can access it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The file should be able to be read from the standard input unless you are using a special shell.

Comment: So something along the lines of `FILE * input = stdin`?

Comment: Just write your program to read from `stdin`. You do not need to care whether stdin input is coming from someone typing or being redirected from a file. That is, you can just use any function that is able to read from stdin. e.g. `scanf` or `fgets(.., .., stdin)`, etc.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Or, you can read from a file, or from `stdin` (by default), `FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;`, then `fgets (..., ..., fp)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a unix shell (zsh, bash, etc.) and do something like `./myProgram <filename`, the program dosn't receive `<filename` in `argv` array. Instead, the shell parses the part with `<` and redirects the program's input so that it come from the file `filename`.

More on i/o redirection [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm)

So, you write exactly as if you were reading from `stdin` (because you *are* reading from stdin):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    char str[200];
    int i;
    scanf("%s", str);
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("%s %d\n", str, i);
}
```